# Solr suggest exact match

Tags: solr, lucene, autosuggest

I am trying to make solr return exact match on suggestion, ex:

- **spellcheck.q=tota** does return **total** in results but
- **spellcheck.q=total** does not return **total** in results.

I am using this field for suggestions:

```xml
<fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any idea how to make Solr returns exact matches on suggest??

Comment: is the analyzer used for indexing and quering is same?

Comment: try replacing the "StandardTokenizerFactory" with "KeywordTokenizerFactory"

Comment: that will index all field text as a single term!

Comment: Do you have the complete spellcheck-query you're making, and the field you're making it against?

Comment: this is the query: localhost:8983/solr/projects/suggest?spellcheck.q=total the field is :   <fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Answer (score 1):

You are using the SpellChecker component, which, as the name indicate, is meant for spellchecking. It returns suggestions for how entry the should be spelled. When the word is spelled correct (which equals a exact match) it returns nothing, which is the reason you dont see the word in the list.

Since Solr 4.7 a new Suggestion component has been added, which is actually implemented for autosuggestion and yields the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this

```
<fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: and my last try is here :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in this wiki page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

`To be used as the basis for a suggestion, the field must be stored.`

Make sure your field is stored.
You field isn't stored so it is returning the data crunched by your indexer.

Comment: You should try to open your index with Luke (https://code.google.com/p/luke/). Look at the stored field and make sure it appears correctly. Let me know how it looks.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem came because you used the old suggest component based on the spellcheck component (I suppose you used a version of solr before 5).

With the old spellcheck/suggest, if the word match it is not return in the response!

Test with the solr.suggestComponent (if present in your version).

see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester

Comment: do not forget to change you spellcheck.q by suggest.q in your request if you used the new suggest